# Masstransit StateMachine

Tags: c#, masstransit, state-machine, saga

I have configured Masstransit like so:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddMassTransitWithRabbitMqAndKafka(this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration, bool registerBrokerHandler = false)
    {
        services.AddMassTransit(x =>
        {
            var test = x.AddLogging(l =>
            {
                l.AddLoggerConfig(configuration);
            });

            services.TryAddSingleton(typeof(ILogger<>), typeof(Logger<>));

            x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
            {
                cfg.Host("rabbitMQ", "/", h =>
                {
                    h.Username(configuration["RabbitMQ:User"]);
                    h.Password(configuration["RabbitMQ:Pass"]);
                });

                cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
            });

            x.TryAddScoped<IUnitOfWork<AuthDbContext>, UnitOfWork<AuthDbContext>>();
            x.TryAddScoped<ISellixGatewayBuyHandlerRepository, SellixGatewayBuyHandlerRepository>();
            x.TryAddScoped<IDiscordBotNotificationRepository, DiscordBotNotificationRepository>();
            x.TryAddScoped<IMariaDbBackupImplementation, MariaDbBackupImplementation>();
            x.TryAddScoped<IMariaDbBackupRepository, MariaDbBackupRepository>();
            x.TryAddScoped<ISellixGatewayBuyHandlerRepository, SellixGatewayBuyHandlerRepository>();
            x.TryAddScoped<ISellixGatewayBuyHandlerImplementation, SellixGatewayBuyHandlerImplementation>();

            x.AddRider(r =>
            {
                r.AddProducer<OrderSubmittedEvent>("Discord-Order-Submitted");
                r.AddProducer<LicenseGrantEvent>("Discord-License-Grant");
                r.AddProducer<LicenseNotificationEvent>("Discord-Notification");
                r.AddProducer<LicenseDatabaseBackupEvent>("Discord-Database-BackupEvent");

                r.AddConsumer<LicenseGrantEventConsumer>();
                r.AddConsumer<LicenseNotificationEventConsumer>();
                r.AddConsumer<LicenseDatabaseBackupEventConsumer>();

                r.AddSagaStateMachine<DiscordStateMachine, SagaDiscord>().InMemoryRepository(); 

                r.UsingKafka((context, cfg) =>
                {
                    cfg.Host("kafka");

                    #region Discord-Order-Submitted
                    cfg.TopicEndpoint<Null, OrderSubmittedEvent>("Discord-Order-Submitted", "Discord", e =>
                    {
                        e.AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest;
                        e.CreateIfMissing(m =>
                        {
                            m.NumPartitions = 10;
                        });
                        e.UseNewtonsoftJsonSerializer();
                        e.UseNewtonsoftJsonDeserializer();
                        e.ConfigureSaga<SagaDiscord>(context);
                    });
                    #endregion
                    #region Discord-License-Grant
                    cfg.TopicEndpoint<Null, LicenseGrantEvent>("Discord-License-Grant", "Discord", e =>
                    {
                        e.AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest;
                        e.CreateIfMissing(m =>
                        {
                            m.NumPartitions = 10;
                        });
                        e.UseNewtonsoftJsonSerializer();
                        e.UseNewtonsoftJsonDeserializer();
                        e.ConfigureSaga<SagaDiscord>(context);
                        e.ConfigureConsumer<LicenseGrantEventConsumer>(context);
                    });
                    #endregion
                    #region Discord-Notification
                    cfg.TopicEndpoint<Null, LicenseNotificationEvent>("Discord-Notification", "Discord", e =>
                    {
                        e.AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest;
                        e.CreateIfMissing(m =>
                        {
                            m.NumPartitions = 10;
                        });
                        e.UseNewtonsoftJsonSerializer();
                        e.UseNewtonsoftJsonDeserializer();
                        e.ConfigureSaga<SagaDiscord>(context);
                        e.ConfigureConsumer<LicenseNotificationEventConsumer>(context);
                    });
                    #endregion
                    #region Discord-Database-BackupEvent
                    cfg.TopicEndpoint<Null, LicenseDatabaseBackupEvent>("Discord-Database-BackupEvent", "Discord", e =>
                    {
                        e.AutoOffsetReset = AutoOffsetReset.Earliest;
                        e.CreateIfMissing(m =>
                        {
                            m.NumPartitions = 10;
                        });
                        e.UseNewtonsoftJsonSerializer();
                        e.UseNewtonsoftJsonDeserializer();
                        e.ConfigureSaga<SagaDiscord>(context);
                        e.ConfigureConsumer<LicenseDatabaseBackupEventConsumer>(context);
                    });
                    #endregion
                });
            });
        });

        return services;
    }
```

And my statemachine

```
public class DiscordStateMachine : MassTransitStateMachine<SagaDiscord>
{
    private readonly ILogger<DiscordStateMachine> _logger;
    public State GrantLicenseState { get; set; }
    public State NotificationReadyState { get; set; }
    public State BackupReadyState { get; set; }

    public Event<OrderSubmittedEvent> OrderSubmittedEvent { get; set; }
    public Event<LicenseGrantEvent> GrantLicenseEvent { get; set; }
    public Event<LicenseNotificationEvent> NotifyEvent { get; set; }
    public Event<LicenseDatabaseBackupEvent> BackupEvent { get; set; }


#pragma warning disable CS8618 // Non-nullable field must contain a non-null value when exiting constructor. Consider declaring as nullable.
    public DiscordStateMachine(ILogger<DiscordStateMachine> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;

        Event(() => OrderSubmittedEvent, x =>
        {
            x.CorrelateById(context => context.Message.CorrelationId);
        });
        Event(() => GrantLicenseEvent, x => { x.CorrelateById(context => context.Message.CorrelationId);});
        Event(() => NotifyEvent, x => { x.CorrelateById(context => context.Message.CorrelationId);});
        Event(() => BackupEvent, x => { x.CorrelateById(context => context.Message.CorrelationId);});

        InstanceState(x => x.CurrentState, GrantLicenseState, NotificationReadyState, BackupReadyState);

        Initially(
            When(OrderSubmittedEvent)
            .Then(context =>
            {
                _logger.LogInformation(1, "Saga Order Submitted Event: {0}", context.Message.CorrelationId);
                context.Saga.CorrelationId = context.Message.CorrelationId;
                context.Saga.Payload = context.Message.Payload;
            })
            .Produce(context => context.Init<LicenseGrantEvent>(new
            {
                CorrelationId = context.Saga.CorrelationId,
                Payload = context.Saga.Payload
            }))
            .Then(context => _logger.LogInformation(1, "Saga Order Submitted Event [License Grant Event Produced]: {0}", context.Message.CorrelationId))
            .TransitionTo(GrantLicenseState));

        DuringAny(
            When(GrantLicenseEvent)
                .Then(context =>
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation(1, "Saga License Grant Event: {0}", context.Message.CorrelationId);
                    context.Saga.CorrelationId = context.Message.CorrelationId;
                    context.Saga.Payload = context.Message.Payload;
                    context.Saga.Quantity = context.Message.Quantity;
                    context.Saga.Time = context.Message.Time;
                    context.Saga.WhichSpec = context.Message.WhichSpec;
                })
                .Then(context => _logger.LogInformation(1, "Saga License Grant Event [License Notification Event Produced]: {0}", context.Message.CorrelationId))
                .TransitionTo(NotificationReadyState),

            When(NotifyEvent)
                .Then(context =>
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation(1, "Saga Notify Event: {0}\n{1}\n{2}\n{3}", context.Message.CorrelationId,
                        context.Message.Quantity, context.Message.Time, context.Message.WhichSpec);

                    context.Saga.CorrelationId = context.Message.CorrelationId;
                })
                .Produce(context => context.Init<LicenseDatabaseBackupEvent>(new
                {
                    CorrelationId = context.Saga.CorrelationId
                }))
                .Then(context => _logger.LogInformation(1, "Saga Notify Event [Backup Event Produced]: {0}", context.Message.CorrelationId))
                .TransitionTo(BackupReadyState),

            When(BackupEvent)
                .Then(context =>
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation(1, "Saga Backup Event: {0}", context.Message.CorrelationId);
                    context.Saga.CorrelationId = context.Message.CorrelationId;
                })
                .Finalize());


        SetCompletedWhenFinalized();
    }
}
```

And a consumer example:

```
public class LicenseGrantEventConsumer : IConsumer<LicenseGrantEvent>
{
    private readonly ILogger<LicenseGrantEventConsumer> _logger;
    private readonly IUnitOfWork<AuthDbContext> _unitOfWork;
    private readonly ISellixGatewayBuyHandlerRepository _license;
    private readonly ITopicProducer<LicenseNotificationEvent> _producer;

    public LicenseGrantEventConsumer(ILogger<LicenseGrantEventConsumer> logger, IUnitOfWork<AuthDbContext> unitOfWork, ISellixGatewayBuyHandlerRepository license, ITopicProducer<LicenseNotificationEvent> producer)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        _license = license;
        _producer = producer;
    }
    public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<LicenseGrantEvent> context)
    {
        try
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Consumer Received Grant License Event: {id} with payload: {Payload}", context.Message.CorrelationId, context.Message.Payload);

            await _unitOfWork.CreateTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable);
            if (context.Message.Payload != null)
            {
                var deserializePayload =
                    JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SellixPayloadNormal.Root>(context.Message.Payload);

                var license = await _license.OrderHandler(deserializePayload ?? throw new NullReferenceException("LicenseGrant Payload Null"));

                await _unitOfWork.Commit();

                await _producer.Produce(new LicenseNotificationEvent
                {
                    Payload = license.Payload,
                    Quantity = license.Quantity,
                    Time = license.Time,
                    WhichSpec = license.WhichSpec,
                    CorrelationId = context.Message.CorrelationId
                });

                _logger.LogInformation("Consumer Finished Grant License Event with CorrelationId: {CorrelationId}", context.Message.CorrelationId);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "License Consumer Error");
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that sometimes it correctly transitions through all the states and consumers.

Sometimes it stops after GrantLicenseState or NotificationReadyState and don't consume them.

Sometimes it transitions through the states, but dont consume.

What seems to always happen is OrderSubmittedEvent & LicenseGrantEvent are being consumed, but sometimes those things as mentioned above happens after.

Any help regarding this is much appreciated.

It's hosted in docker containers:

```
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    platform: linux/amd64
    networks: 
      - private_network
    restart: always
    container_name: zookeeper
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    platform: linux/amd64
    networks: 
      - private_network
    container_name: kafka
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: 'zookeeper:2181'
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: 'PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,PLAINTEXT_INTERNAL://kafka:29092,PLAINTEXT_EXTERNAL://kafka:19092'
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_MIN_ISR: 1
      KAFKA_TRANSACTION_STATE_LOG_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1

  rabbitMQ:
    image:  masstransit/rabbitmq:latest
    platform: linux/amd64
    container_name: rabbitMQ
    networks:
      - private_network
    hostname: rabbitMQ
    restart: always
    environment:
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER=${RABBITMQDEFAULTUSER}
      - RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS=${RABBITMQDEFAULTPASS}
      - RabbitMQ__User=${RabbitMQUser}
      - RabbitMQ__Pass=${RabbitMQPass} 
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "15672:15672"
    volumes:
      - persistedData_RabbitMq:/var/lib/rabbitmq/
      - persistedData_RabbitMq:/var/log/rabbitmq/
      - persistedData_RabbitMq:/etc/rabbitmq/
```

Comment: I see you are new to Stack Overflow. The question above isn't really something that can be easily answered here, as it has a number of external dependencies and files not shown. There are [support](https://masstransit.io/support) options available for MassTransit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Chris Patterson.

In case anyone else run into a similar issue in the future.

What I did to fix this, was adding my Discord.Net client connection handler as scoped and using DI every where it is needed instead of having it as a static class usable by a lot of other projects.

This is causing it not to transition or consume properly.